# Using web3.js in a react redux saga app - uncaught at check call error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to use [`Web3.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) (Ethereum JavaScript API) in a ReactJS app with Redux / Saga.

This is my **GetWeb3** function:

```
const GetWeb3 = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      let web3 = window.web3;
      const alreadyInjected = typeof web3 !== "undefined";
      if (alreadyInjected) {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      } else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
        web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
    });
  });

export default GetWeb3;
```

and I am trying to use this inside a saga like this:

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import truffleContract from "truffle-contract";

import GetWeb3 from "../../../Utils/GetWeb3";
import SimpleStorageContract from "../../../Data/SimpleStorageContract.json";

import { loadWeb3Done, loadWeb3Error } from "./Web3.actionCreators";

export function* loadWeb3(action) {
  try {
    const web3 = yield call(GetWeb3());
    const accounts = yield call(web3.eth.getAccounts());

    console.log('accounts', accounts);

    const contract = truffleContract(SimpleStorageContract);
    contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
    const instance = yield call(contract.deployed());

    yield put(
      loadWeb3Done({
        web3,
        accounts,
        contract: instance
      })
    );
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(loadWeb3Error(e));
  }
}
```

When my app runs with the above, I am seeing this error:

> index.js:2178 uncaught at check call: argument [object Promise] is not
>   a function
>   **stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console** @ index.js:2178
>
> GetWeb3.js:14 Injected web3 detected.

and I am not seeing the console log of `accounts`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: `call` accepts function as parameter, but you are calling the functions instead of passing them as argument. `yield call(GetWeb3())` -> `yield call(GetWeb3)`. and `yield call(web3.eth.getAccounts());` -> `yield call([web3.eth, web3.eth.getAccounts]);`

Comment: Aha, so that's how you call a method on something you've jut initialised; `yield call([web3.eth, web3.eth.getAccounts]);` let me try this.